# How to run TypeScript files from command line?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm having a surprisingly hard time finding an answer to this. With plain Node.JS, you can run any js file with `node path/to/file.js`, with CoffeeScript it's `coffee hello.coffee` and ES6 has `babel-node hello.js`. How do I do the same with Typescript?

My project has a `tsconfig.json` which is used by Webpack/ts-loader to build a nice little bundle for the browser. I have a need for a build step run from the console before that, though, that would use some of the `.ts` files used in the project to generate a schema, but I can't seem to be able to run a single Typescript file without compiling the whole project.

Answer (score 973, accepted):

> How do I do the same with Typescript

You can leave `tsc` running in watch mode using `tsc -w -p .` and it will generate `.js` files for you in a live fashion, so you can run `node foo.js` like normal

## TS Node

There is ts-node : https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node that will compile the code on the fly and run it through node

```
npx ts-node src/foo.ts
```

Comment: What's the difference between these two options?

Comment: tsc writes js to disk. ts-node doesn't need to do that and runs ts on the fly

Comment: just reminder ts-node does not console log from imported modules. For Ex: if you are ts-node fil1.ts and file1.ts uses file2.ts internally, then console logs from file2.ts will not be logged.

Comment: One red herring to be careful of that I ran into and was confusing me. I had a simple TypeScript file named `test.ts` that was never transpiled and had the single line of code: `console.log('hello');` in it. I was running `node test.ts` from the command line and _it worked_ outputting 'hello` which was confusing me. Well if the file is _purely_ valid JavaScript and you run `node myFile.ts` it _still works._ However this isn't a good use case as the minute I added TypeScript code I got an error upon trying to run it which is what I expected. I wish node would alert/error upon running .ts files.

Comment: ts-node FTW. `npm install -g ts-node` makes `ts-node your-script.ts` a breeze.

Comment: one more cool thing with ts-node: you can install it globally together with typescript and then just add this line to your .ts script:

```#!/usr/bin/env ts-node```

and you can run your .ts script just like any OS script (but don't forget about chown +x)

Comment: Since the release of [deno](https://deno.land/), you can now execute `deno run path/to/file.ts` and it will run typescript files in a single command without compiling it to a separate JS file.

Comment: Careful with deno as it is *distinct* from node and code that will work in node might not work in deno (due to built-in and npm nodejs packages) 

Comment: @JMadelaine Deno does compile to a JavaScript module file and writes it to a generated cache directory each time you run the source file. See `DENO_DIR` at https://deno.land/manual@v1.10.1/getting_started/setup_your_environment#environmental-variables

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Comment: As of May 2022 ts-node does support es modules `npx ts-node --esm file.ts` https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node#commonjs-vs-native-ecmascript-modules

Comment: In my case I had to add a `--skipProject` to just ignore everything in `tsconfig.json` and run the file without fancy settings.

Comment: Got to use the `--esm` flag these days: `npx ts-node --esm src/foo.ts`

Answer (score 216):

Run the below commands and install the required packages globally:

```bash
npm install -g ts-node typescript '@types/node'
```

Now run the following command to execute a typescript file:

```bash
ts-node typescript-file.ts
```

Comment: this is the best way to do it IMHO, as `ts-node` also provides TypeScript REPL.

Comment: You can also rely on `npx ts-node yourscript.ts` in case you don't want to use global version.

Comment: [`ts-node` doesn't support ES Modules](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/935#issuecomment-579718641).

Comment: The query for the download no longer valid , try ```npm install typescript --save-dev --global && npm i ts-node -g``` instead

Comment: About `'@types/node'` I recommend taking a look at these links: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node ,
https://www.alura.com.br/artigos/typescript-favoreca-o-uso-de-type-definitions [], 
https://blog.angular-university.io/typescript-2-type-system-how-do-type-definitions-work-in-npm-when-to-use-types-and-why-what-are-compiler-opt-in-types/ . 

Comment: ts-node now [supports ES Modules](https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/imports/), though this support remains experimental because it depends on Node features that are still experimental

Answer (score 121):

We have following steps:

1. First you need to install typescript

   ```sh
   npm install -g typescript
   ```
2. Create one file helloworld.ts

   ```
   function hello(person){
      return "Hello, " + person;
   }
   let user = "Aamod Tiwari";
   const result = hello(user);
   console.log("Result", result)
   ```
3. Open command prompt and type the following command

   ```sh
   tsc helloworld.ts
   ```
4. Again run the command

   ```sh
   node helloworld.js
   ```
5. Result will display on console

Comment: In your case ,we run .js file not .ts file.

Comment: FYI: Be careful this will generate one .js file foreach .ts file

Answer (score 79):

You can also try tsx.
tsx is a CLI command (alternative to node) for seamlessly running TypeScript, it's built upon esbuild so it's very fast.

https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx

Example:

```
npx tsx ./script.ts
```

Comment: Important answer for when speed is critical.

Comment: Also important answer when u just want it to work with no hassle, in my case all alternatives had issues

Comment: > npx tsx --watch ./script.ts
will execute everytime script.ts is modified

Comment: How do I debug with chrome web inspector?

Comment: tsx also works when running it _inside a shell script called from an "npm run" script_. Don't ask why I had to do that. But ts-node doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: use `npx tsx --env-file=.env ./script.ts` to specify the env file

Comment: it does not run the script!

Answer (score 53):

To add to @Aamod answer above, If you want to use one command line to compile and run your code, you can use the following:

Windows:

```bash
tsc main.ts | node main.js
```

Linux / macOS:

```bash
tsc main.ts && node main.js
```

Comment: `npm install typescript -g` to install `tsc` CLI

Comment: Ah the windows 'pipe'

Comment: This wouldn't work if you want to debug typescript source line by line.

Comment: @s2t2 If you're running typescript in your project there's already a `tsc` executable in `/node_modules/.bin/tsc`.
This should really be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 51):

I created [@digitak/esrun](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@digitak/esrun), a thin wrapper around [esbuild](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild) and that executes a TypeScript file almost instantly. `esrun` was made because I was disappointed with `ts-node`: too slow, and just didn't work most of the time.

Advantages of [esrun](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@digitak/esrun) over `ts-node` include:

- very fast (uses [esbuild](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild)),
- can import ESM as well as CJS (just use the libraries of your choice and `esrun` will work out of the box),
- there is an included watch mode, run your script with the `--watch` option and any change to your entry file or any of its dependencies will re-trigger the result
- you can use `esrun` in inspect mode to use the DevTools console instead of your terminal console.

After installing, just run:

```
npx @digitak/esrun file.ts
```

Comment: Omg, exactly what I was looking for, for many many hours ! Couldn't make `ts-node` to work. Simply ran "esrun my-file.ts", and worked  out of the box !

Comment: Maybe a little disclaimer that you're the author of the library?

Comment: @RobinMétral Yeah, I sometimes find disclaimers ridiculous. I didn't post this for my own publicity but to genuinely help people with the same needs as me. `ts-node` was troubles and slowness and I wanted to have a modern typescript runner. I also consider it's not really my work since I've only written a small wrapper around the awesome EsBuild library from Evan W - he is the guy who deserves all the credits.

Comment: Still – [you must disclose any affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) in your answers. In this particular case, too, the library is far from a standard: single contributor, single test, few NPM downloads. esbuild is still a good recommendation I think, but I would recommend using it directly, or via another library like [Estrella](https://github.com/rsms/estrella)

Comment: Oh thx for the link @RobinMétral, didn't know it was mandatory. I will update my answer. This library is nothing more than a 77-lines of code wrapper around Esbuild, no need for a 7-collaborators team or an extended test suite for 77 lines of code. All the work is done by Esbuild. People can use it or ts-node or sucrase-node or anything they prefer. I personnally prefer my library because I encountered less issues. Estrella looks awesome but I would not recommand it for this question (nor Esbuild) as they are both build tools and not running tools.

Comment: I’m not sure why this wasn’t specified, but to (easily) use this do `npx @digitak/esrun index.ts` replacing `index.ts` if required.

Comment: @GinQuin I just wanted to add my thanks for building this. I also found that ts-node doesn't work well with scripts that import/export. You have saved me alot of headaches. It's insane that typescript doesn't already have this functionality built-in to their tooling, so thank you for filling in the gaps.

Comment: Same here. I've tried `ts-node` and `tsx` and `esrun` is the only one that just worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: @GinQuin I posted about TS tools, mentioning `esrun` and Brendan Eich (creator of JavaScript) retweeted it to all his followers: https://twitter.com/mikemaccana/status/1617616516073271296?s=20&t=6FCBeQDRMcZJ07JKvXPvpw

Comment: Thank you @GinQuin. Also on team `esrun` and have been using it with a few projects for the last few months.

Answer (score 48):

#### **Edit: May 2022**

`ts-node` now has an `--esm` flag use it.

#### **Old Answer:**

None of the other answers discuss how to run a TypeScript script that uses modules, and especially modern ES Modules.

First off, [ts-node doesn't work](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/935#issuecomment-579718641) in that scenario, as of March 2020. So we'll settle for `tsc` followed by `node`.

Second, [TypeScript still can't output `.mjs` files](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18442). So we'll settle for `.js` files and `"type": "module"` in `package.json`.

Third, you want clean `import` lines, without specifying the `.js` extension (which would be confusing in `.ts` files):

```
import { Lib } from './Lib';
```

Well, that's non-trivial. Node *requires* specifying extensions on imports, unless you use the [`experimental-specifier-resolution=node`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30520#issuecomment-583705214) flag. In this case, it would enable Node to look for `Lib.js` or `Lib/index.js` when you only specify `./Lib` on the `import` line.

Fourth, there's still a snag: [if you have a different `main` filename than `index.js` in your package, Node won't find it](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/32103).

Transpiling makes things a lot messier than running vanilla Node.

Here's [a sample repo with a modern TypeScript project structure](https://github.com/dandv/typescript-modern-project), generating ES Module code.

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@digitak/esrun which solves the issues mentioned

Comment: Thanks @GinQuin ! esrun did exactly what I expected ts-node to do: SImply run the script with imports.

Comment: Look for my answer ts-node now supports the `--esm` flag. You answer is my fav! Could you update to help future devs :)

Comment: Reviewer note: @bcbrian - there is no need to edit this information in since you posted an answer yourself. It is perfectly natural for new answers to contain updated information - take the credit.

Comment: Adding --esm doesn't solve the required file extensions on imports issue.

Answer (score 20):

Just helpful information - here is newest TypeScript / JavaScript runtime [Deno](https://github.com/denoland/deno).

It was created by the creator of node Ryan Dahl, based on what he would do differently if he could start fresh.

Comment: Here's an example: `deno run https://deno.land/std/examples/welcome.ts`

Comment: this would be my preferred approach, except for import/require issues with node modules, which is non-trivial to fix

Comment: As tools grow to support Deno's security, I see its ease of use increasing. Including how imports need to have the full relative path/url and file extension. `Deno is secure by default. Therefore, unless you specifically enable it, a deno module has no file, network, or environment access for example.` add the extra flags while developing. then lock it down: `deno run --unstable --allow-read --allow-env main.ts` -> https://dev.to/mxfellner/node-js-compatibility-using-npm-packages-in-deno-52hh

Answer (score 12):

For linux / mac you can add the `ts-node-script` shebang.

Install typescript / ts-node globally (see <sup>1</sup> below for non global install):

```
npm install ts-node typescript --save-dev --global
```

Add this as the first line in your `.ts` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ts-node-script
```

Then make the file executable:

```
$ chmod +x ./your-file.ts
```

You can then run the file directly from the command line:

```
$ ./your-file.ts
```

---

Notes:

<sup>1</sup> For non global install you can install local to your project

```
npm install ts-node typescript --save-dev
```

and add the relative path to the shebang script eg:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node-script
```

<sup>2</sup> [Support for shebangs](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#shebang) was officially added in [ts-node v8.9.0](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/releases/tag/v8.9.0).

Answer (score 12):

As of May 2022 `ts-node` does support es modules

```
npx ts-node --esm file.ts
```

you will likely need to add `"type": "module",` to your `package.json`. And some of the imports might be wonky unless you turn on `experimental-specifier-resolution=node`

[npmjs.com/package/ts-node#commonjs-vs-native-ecmascript-modules](https://npmjs.com/package/ts-node#commonjs-vs-native-ecmascript-modules)

Answer (score 12):

Use [bun](https://bun.sh/).

It's faster and has a lot of tooling bundled in.

`bun run ./my-script.ts`

Comment: it's really easy!

Comment: deno too. But you should install either into package.json devDependencies via `npm i --save-dev [bun or deno]` looking in npmjs for the appropriate packages

Answer (score 9):

Write yourself a simple bash wrapper may helps.

```
#!/bin/bash
npx tsc $1 && node ${1%%.ts}
```

Answer (score 7):

Like [Zeeshan Ahmad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58689284), I also think `ts-node` is the way to go. I would also add a shebang and make it executable, so you can just run it directly.

1. Install typescript and ts-node globally:

   ```
   npm install -g ts-node typescript
   ```

   or

   ```
   yarn global add ts-node typescript
   ```
2. Create a file `hello` with this content:

   ```js
   #!/usr/bin/env ts-node-script

   import * as os from 'os'

   function hello(name: string) {
       return 'Hello, ' + name
   }
   const user = os.userInfo().username
   console.log(`Result: ${hello(user)}`)
   ```

   As you can see, line one has the shebang for ts-node
3. Run directly by just executing the file

   ```
   $ ./hello
   Result: Hello, root
   ```

Some notes:

- This [does not seem to work with ES modules](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/935#issuecomment-579718641), as [Dan Dascalescu has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535879/how-to-run-typescript-files-from-command-line/60486808?noredirect=1#comment107106927_60486808).
- See [this issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/995) discussing the best way to make a command line script with package linking, [provided by Kaspar Etter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535879/how-to-run-typescript-files-from-command-line/60486808?noredirect=1#comment107957231_60486808). I have improved the shebang accordingly

---

Update 2020-04-06: Some changes after great input in the comments: Update shebang to use `ts-node-script` instead of `ts-node`, link to issues in ts-node.

Comment: [`ts-node` doesn't support ES Modules](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/935#issuecomment-579718641).

Comment: You can run into many problems with this approach. I documented potential solutions in [this issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/995). In particular, the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env ts-node-script` (also part of `ts-node`) seems to be superior for this purpose. If you want to link your script (e.g. with [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)), things get more complicated as the script mode of `ts-node` does not (yet?) follow symbolic links. I went with `#!/usr/bin/env -S ts-node --project /usr/local/lib/node_modules/<your-project>/tsconfig.json` in the end in my case.

Answer (score 7):

For environments such as [Webstorm](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/188) where the `node` command cannot be changed to `ts-node` or `npx`:

1. `npm install ts-node typescript` (Install dependencies)
2. `node --require ts-node/register src/foo.ts` (Add `--require ts-node/register` to "Node parameters")

Comment: You *can* change the Node interpreter in WebStorm. In the Run/Debug configuration, you can select any binary you want as the Node interpreter.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the command

`tsc index.ts --outDir .temp && node .temp/index.js && rm -rf .temp`
`<<<<<<<<< Compile >>>>>>>>>    <<<<<<< Run >>>>>>>     << Clean >>`

Answer (score 4):

1. Create your TypeScript file (ex. app.ts)
2. `npm i -D typescript ts-node` -> to install the dev dependencies local
3. `npx nodemon app.ts`

Using nodemon, automatically recompile app.ts every time you change the file

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone is insane like me and wants to just run typescript script as though it was a .js script, you can try this. I've written a hacky script that appears to execute the .ts script using node.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

NODEPATH="$HOME/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin" # set path to your node/tsc

export TSC="$NODEPATH/tsc"
export NODE="$NODEPATH/node"

TSCFILE=$1 # only parameter is the name of the ts file you created.

function show_usage() {
    echo "ts2node [ts file]"
    exit 0
}

if [ "$TSCFILE" == "" ]
then
    show_usage;
fi

JSFILE="$(echo $TSCFILE|cut -d"." -f 1).js"

$TSC $TSCFILE && $NODE $JSFILE
```

You can do this or write your own but essentially, it creates the .js file and then uses node to run it like so:

```
# tsrun myscript.ts
```

Simple. Just make sure your script only has one "." else you'll need to change your JSFILE in a different way than what I've shown.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install `ts-node` node module globally.
2. Create node runtime configuration (for IDE) or use `node` in command line to run below file `js` file (The path is for windows, but you can do it for linux as well)
   `~\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js`
3. Give your `ts` file path as a command line argument.
4. Run Or Debug as you like.

Comment: This is the way you need to do it if you want to debug with an IDE! Thanks for this!!

Answer (score 0):

There is also an option to run code directly from the CLI, not the `*.ts` file itself.

It's perfectly described [in the ts-node manual](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node).

1. As a first step, install `ts-node` globally via npm, yarn, or whatever you like.
2. ...and now just use `ts-node -e 'console.log("Hello, world!")'` (*you may also add the `-p` flag for printing code*)

This little command is perfect for checking, does everything installed fine. And for finding some other error, relevant with `tsconfig.json` options.

Answer (score -3):

We can run it using nodemon as well

```
nodemon ./filepath/filename.ts
```

Answer (score -55):

This question was posted in 2015. In 2018, node recognizes both **.js** and **.ts**. So, running **`node file.ts`** will also run.

Comment: Node interprets any file as javascript, so it will only work if the typescript file in question is a valid javascript file itself.

Comment: This will work if file content is valid javascript but extension is ts. Node does not care what the extension is, as long as content is valid javascript.