# importing typescript functions from one file to another

Tags: node.js, typescript, import

I am trying to import a function for use in my `main.ts` file, but i either get 'is not a module' or 'unexpected import token' when i use `node main.ts` to run my file.

These are not node modules and i'm not using any framework.

```
// main.ts
import * as forms from "./script/form";

forms.autoForm();

// form.ts
export function autoForm() {
    // something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They *are* modules, and depending on your typescript configuration can be emitted as many different module formats.

Typescript is a compile time language, in order to run it it must be transformed into javascript first.

You can also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535879/how-to-run-typescript-files-from-command-line) for details on how to run typescript files directly with node using tsc watch mode.