# How do i get the output of this following typescript code using command prompt ?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
class Book{
    public title : string;
    public year  : number;

    constructor( title :string ,year:number){
        this.title = title;
        this.year  = year ; 


    }
}
var details = new Book("werr",2017);
console.log(details);
```

I'm a still beginner to Typescript.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: do u have `tsc ` file?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you trying to run this code and view the result in your command prompt? Have you tried [installing the TypeScript compiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/#download-links) and using it?

Comment: yes i did try . And its compiling fine. But how can i get the out put of that particular code.tsc app1.ts

Comment: you can check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535879/how-to-run-typescript-files-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

The command is

> tsc <file_name>.ts && node <file_name>.js

You should have nodeJs installed in your system to run the above command.
You can download NodeJs from here https://nodejs.org/en/

Assuming your TypeScript filename is ***main.ts***

Then the command will be

> tsc main.ts && node main.js

If you wish then you can run it seperately also.
First Compile using the following command

> tsc main.ts

Then use the following command to run

> node main.js