# Unexpected Token error on a PARAMETERIZED FUNCTION

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am new to Angular. I was trying to write a function. This compiles without the arguments. but the arguments it gives errors.

Code in Play.ts

```
function printperson(name:string, age:number)
{
console.log('Name: ${name} age: ${age}')
}
printperson("Billy", 8);
```

Command Executed

node play.ts

Error

> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
>   function printperson(name:string, age:number)
>   ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token :     at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
>   at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)     at Module._compile
>   (module.js:543:28)     at Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:580:10)     at Module.load (module.js:488:32)     at
>   tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)     at Function.Module._load
>   (module.js:439:3)     at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)     at run
>   (bootstrap_node.js:423:7)     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:147:9)

Comment: Not 100% because I've never tried to make Node execute a Typescript file but im pretty sure it wont. Think you need to build first to get JS, then node will be happy with it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535879 this post confirms, youll need to build it to JS first. Node cant yet execute TS