# What is correct way how to create functional component in react using typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

What is correct way how to create functional component in react using typescript ?

1. Should I use `interface` or type for `props`?
2. Should I use `React.FC` or `React.FunctionComponent`?
3. How can I validate `props` using `eslint`?

Right now, my typically components looks like:

```
interface IProps {
  color: string;
}

const Example = (props: IProps) => {
  const { color } = props;

  return (
    <>
      {color}
    </>
  );
};
```

I am not sure if it best way...

Also I don`t know how to validate props using`eslint`, for example when I want to pass down color as a number..

Comment: React.FC and React.FunctionComponent are the same.

Comment: Your code is almost there. You just need to change `const Example = (props: IProps) => {` to `const Example: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {`. In addition, your interface is fine!

Answer (score 4):

1. Both are used frequently in the community. I prefer `type` as I find it easier to use, but you can read here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.10 and make your own opinion.
2. `React.FC` is shorthand for `React.FunctionComponent`
3. props will be validated by the TypeScript static analysis.

I found this pattern helpful when starting with function components:

```
type Props {
  color: string;
}

const Example: React.FC<Props> = ({color}: Props) => {

  return (
    <>
      {color}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you, is there any option how to run only `TypeScript static analysis` from command line? I would like to run it before commit after eslint check. Or do you mean  TSLINT?

Comment: If you bootstrap your project with `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` it'll already be there for you by default and if you break the rules of TypeScript it'll complain while running `npm start`. For running it from command line, see e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535879/how-to-run-typescript-files-from-command-line/33536053

Answer (score -1):

By the [Maximilian Schwarzmüller](https://twitter.com/maxedapps) guides the best approach is:

```js
import React from 'react';
import type { FC } from  'react';

interface SampleProps {
  color: string;
}

const Sample: FC<SampleProps> = ({ color }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {color}
    </>
  );
};
```