# How do I run a node script in a typescript react project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I have a React project, and it includes talking to an API.

I have a module defined in the project that abstracts away the api access.

So for example it has methods like `addFoo` and `getFoos`. I would like to use this module from a script that I would like to run directly on the command line. The purpose of the script is to load a bunch of data into a database via the api.

When I use plain `.js`, it seems to be fairly easy to just run `> node path/to/file`. The relative import paths work fine.

**Issue**

When I use `.ts` it doesn't work. It complains that it can't find the module.

**Question**
What's the right way to run a `.ts` CLI script in a React project directly? Or is this the wrong way to do this?

Thanks !

Comment: nodejs doesn't understand ts. you should translate it to js before use it.

Comment: Hi, install `ts-node`. It should get you sorted. [See this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535879/how-to-run-typescript-files-from-command-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MwamiTovi's response above was close however I additionally had to set `{"module": "commonjs"}`.

```
ts-node -O '{"module":"commonjs"}' src/tools/foo.ts
```

Answer (score 3):

add `ts-node` property to your `tsconfig.json`. For example below:

```
{
  "ts-node": { // ts-node automated configuration using commonjs
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "CommonJS"
    }
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmit": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["./src", "./*.json", "./*.ts", "snapshot3.js"],
  "typeAcquisition": { "enable": true },
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "**/tmp/**", "**/build/**", "**/dist/**"]
}
```

then run single `tsx` file:

```bash
ts-node to/single/file.tsx
```

when you need some options to `ts-node` just modify `tsconfig.json` property `ts-node`

**OR**
using direct ts-node ESM experimental without removing {"type": "module"} in package.json

```bash
cross-env-shell NODE_ENV=development node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm -r dotenv/config "src/to/file.ts"
```

`cross-env-shell NODE_ENV=development` is **optional**

Comment: Thanks a lot, that completely did the trick for me! Didn't have to set any other options.

Comment: yeah, no need setup anything. just add `ts-node` property and run `ts-node to/single/file.tsx` and done.

Comment: @Djima: nope, without setting modules to CommonJS it doesn't work since create-react-app sets modules to "esnext"

Comment: this also works `cross-env-shell NODE_ENV=development node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm -r dotenv/config "src/to/file.ts"`