# Nothing prints to terminal using a 2D array of numbers in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Trying to solve a leetcode problem. But, I am getting hung up on something that I feel like should be easy. I am trying to print the test input to terminal before going ahead with this problem. Any idea why this portion of my code is not working? Please don't solve the whole leetcode problem for me. I should also add that I am running this file using `tsc longestincreasingpathinmatrix.ts`. So, I do not think that is the problem.

```
interface firstHashmap<arg> {
  (arg: number): number;
}

function allHashmaps<arg>(arg: number): number {
  return arg;
}

function longestIncreasingPath(matrix: number[][]): number {
  // number: number[][] - list we using :)
  let myHashMap: firstHashmap<number> = allHashmaps;

  for(let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {

     for(let j = 0; j < matrix[j].length; j++) {

        console.log(matrix[i][j]);  // give me the numbers
     }
  }


return 7;





// two lists
// square of numbers
// longest path in square
// can move left right, right, up, or, down
// example is giving me the answer

// hash map - sort
// all increasing numbers any amount

// the numbers must be sorted for the hashmap to work
// how to store an array of arrays in a hashmap
// the numbers start from lowest and go to the highest
// and there can be any amount = if there are too many numbers they won't fit = Max size of hashmap for constant time lookup

// refer to two lists using a hashmap?
};

let testMatrix = [[9,9,4],[6,6,8],[2,1,1]];
longestIncreasingPath(testMatrix);
```

Comment: I think you meant to `matrix[i].length` instead of `matrix[j].length` in your second `for` cycle.

Comment: Also `tsc` command only compiles your code into JavaScript. You have to run it somewhere (browser / nodejs). You can read more at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535879/how-to-run-typescript-files-from-command-line).

Comment: Very helpful! @Jax-p I really appreciate it.