# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' in TypeScript file using Next.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js

I am working on a project using Next.js with TypeScript, for the first time, and Node.js

I have done a few tutorials for TypeScript, getting it to run with Node.js fine. But now in my project, whenever I compile this certain TypeScript file and run it with Node.js (`$ node src/options.ts`)), it get a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'" error, not recognizing TypeScript syntax.

This is the line in question that gets the error (it errors on the first colon after "text").

**Error (up to the first "at" line):**

```
function allUpperCase(text: string): string {
                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "cap-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "jest --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "eslint": "8.49.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.19",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.6.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

I have researched a bit, but I haven't found threads with this exact error. I have however tried installing TypeScript and ts-node (on top of installing Next.js with TypeScript) and updating node to version 18.12.1 directly in the root directory, and updating the .eslintrc.json file to be

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

I have also tried changing the "module" in the tsconfig to "commonjs", but none of these things have not fixed the issue. When I compile it and run the .js file (with `node src/options.js`), it works fine, but the error occurs whenever I try to run the .ts file. This has never been an issue the other times I have run .ts files, but now that I'm using TypeScript from Next.js, it gives that syntax error.

Comment: What if you try `npx ts-node src/options.ts`?

Comment: @ghybs Thank you. That gave me another error, but a different one: "SyntaxError Unexpected token 'export'"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run TypeScript files from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535879/how-to-run-typescript-files-from-command-line)