# How to run a Typescript file (including importing NPM packages) on the fly?

Tags: node.js, typescript

How to run a Typescript ... script directly, including imports from NPM, without the need for a `package.json`?

Suppose I want to write a quick script to alter a bunch of files quickly e.g.:

```
// my-script.ts

import fs from "fs";
import { someFunc } from "some-dep@^4";  // dep pulled from NPM during run

fs.readdir(process.argv[2], (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    someFunc(file);
  });
});
```

I'd like to run this easily, from a terminal, such as:

```bash
<cmd> my-script
```

Where `<cmd>` is whatever program allows me to do this. Does this mystery program exist?

TL;DR: I want to be able to run TS files (with NPM modules) as if they were bash scripts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run TypeScript files from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535879/how-to-run-typescript-files-from-command-line)

Comment: I don't think so, because it would require a `package.json` and running `npm install`. I just want to write and run the script, and have modules be installed/handled for me.

Along with `ts-node`, there is also `esrun` which do similar things but I don't think either "solves" what I'm asking.

Comment: If you want to include a package without having a package.json, use [Deno](https://deno.com/). It allows inclusions in the manner of your example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use npm module in DENO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61821038/how-to-use-npm-module-in-deno)