# Typescript is not letting me use ":"

Tags: node.js, typescript

this code:

```ts
let no: number;
no = 0
console.log(typeof no)
```

```
Uncaught SyntaxError Z:\Typescript\index.ts:1
let no: number;
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1290:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1342:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
    at <anonymous> (node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49)
Process exited with code 1
```

Comment: How did you run the TS script?

Comment: with node, "node index.ts"

Answer (score 0):

See [transpilers](https://nodeshift.dev/nodejs-reference-architecture/development/typescript/#transpilers)

> Node.js does not support running TypeScript natively, so it must first be transpiled to JavaScript.

You can't run the TypeScript script via `node script.ts` directly, you can use [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) to run it.

```
npx ts-node script.ts
```

Or, use `tsc` to compile your TS code to JS code, and then you can run it by `node script.js`. See [Node.js with TypeScript](https://nodejs.org/en/learn/getting-started/nodejs-with-typescript)

Or, use [tsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx#nodejs-loader) as a Node.js loader

> To use tsx as a Node.js loader, pass it in to the --import flag. This will add TypeScript & ESM support for both Module and CommonJS contexts.

```bash
node --import tsx ./file.ts
```

[How to run TypeScript files from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535879/how-to-run-typescript-files-from-command-line)

Comment: ... or use Bun which handles TypeScript natively

Comment: it worked running ts-node, thank you

Comment: Why link to another Stack Overflow post in your answer? Just vote to close as a duplicate